# Using org-map-entries to add properties to all entries with tags

Tags: org-mode, org-tags

I'm trying to make a function that will allow me to add properties to all entries in an org file that contain a particular tag ("drill"):

```lisp
(defun add-to-chinese-anki ()
  (interactive)
  (org-entry-put (point) "ANKI_DECK" "Chinese Org Notes")
  (org-entry-put (point) "ANKI_NOTE_TYPE" "chinese-org-drill")
  (org-entry-put (point) "ANKI_TAGS" "languages")
  )

(defun add-all-to-chinese-anki ()
  (interactive)
  (org-map-entries (lambda () (add-to-chinese-anki) "drill" 'file))
  )
```

However the above code is adding the tags to every entry in the file, and not filtering by tag. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to org-map-entries is wrong - you have a misplaced paren. It should be

```el
   ...
   (org-map-entries (lambda () (add-to-chinese-anki)) "drill" 'file)
   ...
```

Note that the `lambda` is not necessary. The following works just as well:

```el
   ...
   (org-map-entries #'add-to-chinese-anki "drill" 'file)
   ...
```

For more complicated matching, the [Matching tags and properties](https://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html#Matching-tags-and-properties) section of the manual is indispensable: you can read it locally with `C-h i g(org) Matching tags RET`.

Comment: Thanks for this!

Comment: One further question on this: do you know is it possible to skip entries which inherit the tag? Or in other words, to only run the function for the parent entry and not the child entries?

Comment: Try `let`-binding `org-use-tag-inheritance` to nil around the `org-map-entries` call. Untested.

Comment: Thank you - it works :)